# Ruby on Rails: Passing parameters to a method under class <<self

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, ruby-on-rails-4, smtp

I'm having a problem passing data from a controller to method under `class <<self`, for some reason I keep getting the error `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` and cannot work out why I get this error or how I can solve it.

My app/controllers/emails_controller code is:

```
def create
    # Make a new email
    @email = Email.new(email_params)
    # For the email, store the user id as the id of the user logged in
    @email.user_id = session[:user_id]  
    # store the user id
    @user = session[:user_id]
    # if the email has saved in the database
    if @email.save
        email_to_name = @email.to_name
        # split the email addresses selected by the ";"
        @emails = (email_params[:to]).split("; ")
        # for each email address selected do the following
        @emails.each do |emailaddress|
            # the "to" section of the email is to one email address
            @email.to = emailaddress
            # find who to address the email to using the Contact model
            @email.to_name = address_email_to(email_to_name, @email.prefix, emailaddress)
            # find the contact the user wants to email
            contact = Contact.find_by_email(emailaddress).id
            # generate a unsubscribe token
            @unsubscribe = Rails.application.message_verifier(:unsubscribe).generate(contact)       
            # PASS THE ACCOUNT ID TO THE SMTP SETTINGS METHOD IN MY MAILER
            UserEmails.smtp_settings(@email.account_id)
            # send the email
            UserEmails.send_email(@email, @unsubscribe, @email.logo).deliver_now
        end
        # show the email
        redirect_to @email, notice: 'Email was successfully created.'
    # if not saved
    else
        # go back to the new email page
        redirect 'new'
    end
  end

private 
def email_params 
    res = params.require(:email).permit(:account_id, :cc, :bcc, :subject, :greeting, :to_name, :prefix, :message, :from_name, :logo, to: []) 
    res[:to] = res[:to].join('; ')
    res 
end
```

And my app/mailers/user_emails.rb is:

```
class UserEmails < ApplicationMailer

    if Rails.env.development?
        class <<self
          def smtp_settings(account)
            options = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/mailers.yml")[Rails.env]['send_email']
            @@smtp_settings = {
              :address              => 'smtp.gmail.com',
              :port                 => 587,
              :domain               => 'my-domain.com',
              :authentication       => 'plain',
              # FIND THE USER-NAME IN THE ACCOUNT MODEL
              :user_name            => Account.find_by_id(account).email,
              :password             => 'my password', 
            }
          end
        end
    end
    def send_email(email, unsubscribe, logo)
        @url  = 'http://localhost:3000/users/login'
        @email = email
        @unsubscribe = unsubscribe
        @logo = logo
        mail(from: "#{@email.from_name} <#{@email.account.email}>", to: @email.to, cc: @email.cc, bcc: @email.bcc, subject: @email.subject, message: @email.message)
    end
end
```

The log reads:

```
Started POST "/emails" for ::1 at 2016-09-09 11:11:15 +0100
Processing by EmailsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"rCvqJpUNAMker3u6R5sOLjP317oN33t7LSAbJoul1nNkfRt/WwJYT+4vS/fmNW37/XzSOREqafIj/Dqf1k330Q==", "email"=>{"from_name"=>"Ben Smith", "account_id"=>"30", "to"=>["email@gmail.com", ""], "logo"=>"", "subject"=>"", "greeting"=>"No Greeting", "to_name"=>"No Name", "prefix"=>"No", "message"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Email"}
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  begin transaction
  [1m[36mSQL (1.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "emails" ("account_id", "subject", "greeting", "to_name", "prefix", "message", "from_name", "logo", "to", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)[0m  [["account_id", 30], ["subject", ""], ["greeting", ""], ["to_name", "No Name"], ["prefix", "No"], ["message", ""], ["from_name", "Ben Smith"], ["logo", ""], ["to", "email@gmail.com; "], ["user_id", 2], ["created_at", "2016-09-09 10:11:15.382459"], ["updated_at", "2016-09-09 10:11:15.382459"]]
  [1m[35m (205.0ms)[0m  commit transaction
  [1m[36mContact Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "contacts".* FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."email" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["email", "email@gmail.com"]]
  [1m[35mAccount Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT  "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 30]]

UserEmails#send_email: processed outbound mail in 6.0ms
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 234ms (ActiveRecord: 206.0ms)

ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)):
  app/mailers/user_emails.rb:5:in `smtp_settings'
  app/mailers/user_emails.rb:34:in `send_email'
  app/controllers/emails_controller.rb:58:in `block in create'
  app/controllers/emails_controller.rb:46:in `each'
  app/controllers/emails_controller.rb:46:in `create'


  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (4.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (1470.1ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (13.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (1370.1ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (3191.2ms)
```

For background information, what I'm trying to do is change the SMTP server settings per each logged in user, and I'm testing whether this would work by changing the user-name setting - if this works then I intend to also configure the other smtp settings for each user. E.g. the system stores an address, port, domain, authentication user-name, and password for each user, when user 1 sends an email these are all configured as per their settings, when user 2 sends an email these are configured as per their settings. I am only including user-name as a test at the minute to see if this theory would work.

Can someone help me solve my issue?

Comment: Mind to post the first 5-7 lines of the stacktrace?

Comment: In `app/mailers/user_emails.rb:34` in the method `send_email` you call this `smtp_settings` without parameters. Controller has likely nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Ok, I have also included the `send_email` method, but I don't understand how this would be the problem?

Comment: What line is 34? Also, you have included the instance method `send_mail`, while the problematic one is the class method.

Comment: The line is `email(from: "#{@email.from_name} <#{@email.account.email}>", to: @email.to, cc: @email.cc, bcc: @email.bcc, subject: @email.subject, message: @email.message)`

Comment: @BenSmith, you would have to include `app/mailers/user_emails.rb` here if you want a definitive answer.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but I have already included this in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`smtp_settings` method is already defined in ActionMailer as method with 0 parameters. You redefined it as a method with 1 parameter. This causes current error `app/mailers/user_emails.rb:34:in`send_email'`.`mail`method is calling`smtp_settings` without any parameters. One solution is to just rename your method to something that won't conflict with already existing methods available in ActionMailer. But I think this approach is not good.

What you can do is to pass your SMTP settings to `mail` method as `delivery_method_options` hash. Here is an example

```
def send_email(email, unsubscribe, logo)
  @url  = 'http://localhost:3000/users/login'
  @email = email
  @unsubscribe = unsubscribe
  @logo = logo

  account = Account.find_by_id(email.account)
  # You can change here all SMTP settings
  delivery_method_options = {
    :address              => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    :port                 => 587,
    :domain               => 'my-domain.com',
    :authentication       => 'plain',
    :user_name            => account.email,
    :password             => 'my password', 
  }

  mail(
    from: "#{@email.from_name} <#{@email.account.email}>",
    to: @email.to,
    cc: @email.cc,
    bcc: @email.bcc,
    subject: @email.subject,
    message: @email.message,
    delivery_method_options: delivery_method_options
  )
end
```

Comment: For reference, I believe what you're trying to do is documented here:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.0/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-emails-with-dynamic-delivery-options

Comment: That's solved my problem! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score -2):

I don't if i am wrong but in your controller code
 @email = Email.new(email_params)

you have not defined your email_params as i suppose its you defined params.

Comment: I don't see the relevance of email_params here, I have included them in my question now nevertheless.